# Border radius on Entry Xamarin Forms PCL

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin, custom-renderer

Is there a way to set a border radius on an Entry in Xamarin's XAML, or by using a custom renderer or something ?

Everything I've tried up to now has no effect, but for my application it would be really better if I had round borders.

Thank you in advance for your answer !

PS : I've checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37584006/how-to-make-round-corner-entry-control-xamarin-forms) but I've not found my answer there :)

Comment: Well, as far as I remember I did something similar using two elements... You can try to use an entry without border and transparent background, and set a second element behind it which will render the border radius...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Round corner Entry Control Xamarin.Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37584006/how-to-make-round-corner-entry-control-xamarin-forms)

Comment: Thank you @GileadKenzo, that's exactly what I've done with the answer of Alessandro Caliaro just below :)

Comment: Wellcome, glad you get it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a grid with 1 row and 1 column
Inside the grid you can add your Entry and, for example, this [control](https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/tree/master/RoundedBoxView), in the same (the only) cell. You should have an Entry with rounded corners...

This is another useful control ([XFShape](https://github.com/vincentgury/XFShapeView)). Create shapes content views from shared code for your mobile apps! For Android and iOS.

Answer (score 3):

I've posted this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51153642/960691) too, but for convenience I'll just paste it below:

I'm not sure if there's something wrong with this approach or not, because it seems so simple but no one's suggesting it.

But I don't see why you can't just use a `Frame` with `IsClippedToBounds` set to `true`. That gives you a built-in corner radius, which you can then adjust as needed.

```
        <Grid>               
             <Frame
                   CornerRadius     ="20"
                   IsClippedToBounds="true">
                <Editor />
            </Frame>
         </Grid>
```

I'm currently using this solution and it works for me.